# Why the time execution of a "for loop" in Python with zip is not roughly the same in two equivalent contextt

Tags: time, zip, python-multiprocessing

I am running the same "for loop" in Python using the same function with objects of the same size in two different but equivalent context. However the computational time of the two loops is not the same. In one case it is three times the computational time of the other case. Here is the code :

```
result = multiproc_map(local_analysis, state_batches)
for ii, (ATii,muii) in zip(state_batches, result):
   AT[:,ii] = ATii 
   mu[ii]  = muii
```

Here are the diiferent execution time (in sec.) of the portion of code above in the two cases :

> Time of execution of multiproc_map : 9.5367431640625e-07
>   4.069389343261719
>
> Time of execution of the "for loop": 13.779568910598755
>   0.0259706974029541

In both cases the shape of the objects local_analysis and state_batches are exactly the same.

In the end I would like to understand why the execution time is different in both cases and what I can do to make the execution time closer to 4s. in the two cases.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Of course, I can provide further explanation and details if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution but not an explanation to this problem. As I was using this loop in two different cases, I could trace the origin of the bug. I finally found that there was a difference in the time execution of the "for loop" if I change the position of the parameters in the definition of the function and use keywords arguments. Here is the old definition of the function:

```
hybrid_dual_resolution(N,Nl,Nhs,Nls,alpha,betaH1,betaH2,betaH3,betaL1,betaL2,betaL3,
                       opt_file_hr,opt_file_lr,loc_radh,loc_radl,upd_a,
                       infl=1.0,rot=False,mp=False,taper='GC',**kwargs):
```

Here is the new definition of the function where I give the arguments as keywords arguments:

```
def hybrid_dual_resolution(opt_file_hr=None,opt_file_lr=None,upd_a='DEnKF',
                           N=3,Nhs=200,Nl=32,Nls=200,loc_radh=17.7,loc_radl=8.75,
                           alpha=0.04,
                           betaH1=1.,betaH2=0.,betaH3=0.,
                           betaL1=0.,betaL2=1.,betaL3=0.,
                           taper='GC',infl=1.0,
                           rot=False,mp=False,**kwargs):
```

And now the time of execution of the loop is the same in both cases and close to the minimum time I mentioned in the previous post.

I am quite surprised by this bug. Do you think that passing the arguments as keywords arguments can change the execution time of the "for loop" ?